"Failed to start SceneBuilder" Scenebuilder doesn't open in IntelliJ when pressing "Open In SceneBuilder" on fxml file
I have an fxml that I am trying to open through IntelliJ by right clicking, going to the bottom and presing "Open In Scenebuilder". I get this error message:
Failed to start SceneBuilder:
"C:\Users\m\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Scene Builder\SceneBuilder.lnk" C:/Users/m/IdeaProjects/test/src/main/java/com/example/test/test.fxml
The first path is where I have SceneBuilder installed. Latest version via Gluon.
The second path is where the fxml file is, which is called test.
I have the latest version of JDK and and SDK downloaded via Gluon as well. I have added the "lib" folder that came with SDK in my library settings.
This seems like a simple issue with a simple solution, but I'm new to this and hopelessly inadequate to deal with even this. Any help will be massively appreciated!
Much love to you all
I have tried adding a VM option but it makes no difference. I was told this was a necessary part of the step to make SceneBuilder work through Eclipse, so I tried it with IntelliJ whic is what I use. The VM path code used:
--module-path "PATH TO MY SDK LIB FOLDER" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
I tried opening a new project and simply using the base code to just open it, but to no avail.
I have attempted to open an fxml file bith from src -> main -> java-> com.example.test folder within my project and also from src -> resources -> com.example.test.
I have tried different versions of Scenebuilder and javafx SDK.

"Latest version" will no longer be correct once the next version is released. Better to explicitly state what versions you are using.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Did you try just opening the file directly in SceneBuilder, without using IntelliJ?

I would also try specifying the path to the actual executable, not to the shortcut.

Yes, that's it! The path lead to the shortcut, not the executable. I knew there was a simple solution, I'll never make that mistake again. Thank you!

For future readers:
The problem was that the path to SceneBuilder lead to its shortcut, not to its executable.
Solved by the author him-/herself.
